# wildfly did not find jar inside war

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, war, ear

After changing ear to war, wildfly 10 cant find the jar file from jboss-deployment-structure.xml from sub-deployment section. There is no gui.ejb.jar in war after project buildin and I copy it to war manually. I try to root folder and to WEB-INF lib. Help please how to fix it.

> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYSRV0166: Sub deployment gui.ejb.jar in
>   jboss-deployment-structure.xml was not found. Available sub
>   deployments:      at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.subDeploymentNotFound(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:288)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
>     ... 5 more

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices"/>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.services-sts"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.ws-security"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.ws-policy"/>
            <module name="org.apache.xerces"/>
            <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" export="true"services="export"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="gui.ejb.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.xerces"/>
            <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" export="true"services="export"/>
            <module name="javax.xml.ws.api" export="true" />
            <module name="javax.jws.api" export="true" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I copied gui.ejb.jar to WEB-INF/classes but there is th same jar not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

A `WAR` deployment does not have a sub-deployment. You can remove the `<sub-deployment/>` element and it will be inherited from the main deployment element.

As a side note it looks a bit weird to both include and exclude the `org.slf4j` module. If you're attempting to use you're own slf4j binding you'd need to keep it excluded and include an slf4j-api and binding library.